# Java RMI with JFrame - Get text from client to GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, rmi

Hey i just started with Java, RMI and JFrame about 2 weeks ago.
I'm doing a game, it works fine as a console but now i'm adding a GUI and i'm getting confused about how to get the Remote Client messages to my Text Area

Remote Client Interface

```
public interface IRemoteClientObject extends Remote {
    public void notifyLogin(String player) throws RemoteException;
    public void notifyLogout(String player) throws RemoteException;
    public void notifyStatus(String player, PlayerStatus status) throws RemoteException;
    public boolean challenge(String player) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Remote Client

```
    public class RemoteClientObject extends UnicastRemoteObject implements
        IRemoteClientObject {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7209335248515276286L;

    /**
     * @throws RemoteException
     */
    public RemoteClientObject() throws RemoteException {

    }

    @Override
    public void notifyLogin(String player) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("\n" + player + " joined the game"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyLogout(String player) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("\n" + player + " left the game");   
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyStatus(String player, PlayerStatus status) throws RemoteException {

        if (status.equals(PlayerStatus.PLAYING)) 
        {
            System.out.println("\n" + player + " is now playing");
        }
        else if (status.equals(PlayerStatus.READY)) 
        {
            System.out.println("\n" + player + " is available to play");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("\n" + player + " is unavailable to play");
        }
    }

}
```

In my program without any GUI, for example when a player login (it sends a message to all players with that notification)

```
for (Player player : serverObject.getPlayers()) 
                  {
                     player.getClient().notifyLogin(username);
                  }
```

But now i don't want that text in the System.out, i want it in a text area

[image]

So can anyone make me a description about how to do this?Code is not the most important, i just want to understand how this works from a remote client to GUI (JTextArea)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you have already. If the GUI in the picture is already built and you have your JTextArea object created, then just replace the line `System.out.println(...)` with `myTextArea.setText(...)` or `myTextArea.append(...)` depending if you want to keep previous content or replace it.

Comment: The GUI is built, but they are different files. The Remote Client has the remote methods for the clients, the GUI is a runnable file to run in the client local machine.

Comment: @wormwood87 Then you can either make your JTextArea public so your remote class can access it or in your GUI file add a public method to add the text which your remote class can call.

Comment: I'm a little noob in this things but i don't think a remote class is supposed to try to access a class that is in a local machine.

Comment: @wormwood87 I think you don't fully understand the remote class idea as you most eloquently stated. I will edit my answer to include more details. Can you post your IRemoteClientObject and tell me where it is located in the path structure and where RemoteClientObject is located?

Comment: First of all, `challenge` method is not realized in your RemoteClientObject class, but I assume you just removed it for the post. I'm also very confused with extending UnicastRemoteObject, it is a subclass or RemoteServer, and you use it in what seems to be a client. is your application a server with many clients connecting to it? (BTW, we moved to discuss RMI structure, your initial question can still be solved if you do what I initially said in the reply.)

Comment: I solved the problem, you didn't gave me the direct answer but you made me think and i solved it. instead of the system.out i called player.messageArea.append("text here"). rookie mistake lol.

Answer (score 0):

With my understanding you would have to add a button listener to a button (or a mouse listener for the text box) that would look for a certain keystroke (maybe the enter button) or you could even add a JButton to your GUI that the user would click to "submit" their text in that text area.

In the button listener you would just write something like `JTextArea.getText();` (the "JTextArea" would just be whatever you called the text area variable.

Comment: I have a listener for my login button and it's working with the remote methods that i have, but of couse the output in this methods goes to the console and i don't want that.